# How to search using json and show selected project details form search result in html?

Tags: javascript, css, html, search

I have a json file called default.json. In search project name or project id in search field. Selected result form search box should show project details and get selected side bar project name.

here is the result showed in json:

```
    "projects": [
    {
        "instances": null,
        "name": "decodingideas",
        "projectid": "decodingideas-147616",
        "projectnumber": 334691107943,
        "orgid": "",
        "orgname": "",
        "parentid": "",
        "parenttype": ""
    },
    {
        "instances": null,
        "name": "pupil-workers",
        "projectid": "pupil-workers",
        "projectnumber": 455648594684,
        "orgid": "",
        "orgname": "",
        "parentid": "",
        "parenttype": ""
    },
```

Search box html code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top flex-md-nowrap p-0" 
  style="background-color:#3B78E7">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"  href="#">GCP Projects</a>
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" 
placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
    <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the screenshot which i needed:
    [image]

here is the screenshot 2 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). It is easy to use and very helpful library.